# using custom message box in PowerShell script - how to make it support multi-lines and to support right-to-left Languages like Arabic

Tags: powershell, arabic, multiline, right-to-left

I have PowerShell script and need to use message box to alert but I found this [Powershell message box](https://smsagent.blog/2017/08/24/a-customisable-wpf-messagebox-for-powershell/comment-page-1/?unapproved=6305&moderation-hash=2fdf2fa63f7717add7ea2237c6c3374a#comment-6305)

my question is to make the powershell message box above in the link to support multi-lines and to support right-to-left Languages like Arabic.

Comment: The script you are referring to is not VBScript, but PowerShell. More precise, it's a message box in WPF as a PowerShell function

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to show you how you can use this function in Powershell :

---

```
# PowerShell function to display a customizable WPF message box / window
# https://gist.github.com/SMSAgentSoftware/0c0eee98a673b6ac34f5215ea6841beb
# https://smsagent.wordpress.com/2017/08/24/a-customisable-wpf-messagebox-for-powershell/
cls
Function New-WPFMessageBox {

    # For examples for use, see my blog:
    # https://smsagent.wordpress.com/2017/08/24/a-customisable-wpf-messagebox-for-powershell/
    
    # CHANGES
    # 2017-09-11 - Added some required assemblies in the dynamic parameters to avoid errors when run from the PS console host.
    
    # Define Parameters
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        # The popup Content
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0)]
        [Object]$Content,

        # The window title
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1)]
        [string]$Title,

        # The buttons to add
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)]
        [ValidateSet('OK','OK-Cancel','Abort-Retry-Ignore','Yes-No-Cancel','Yes-No','Retry-Cancel','Cancel-TryAgain-Continue','None')]
        [array]$ButtonType = 'OK',

        # The buttons to add
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=3)]
        [array]$CustomButtons,

        # Content font size
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=4)]
        [int]$ContentFontSize = 14,

        # Title font size
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=5)]
        [int]$TitleFontSize = 14,

        # BorderThickness
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=6)]
        [int]$BorderThickness = 0,

        # CornerRadius
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=7)]
        [int]$CornerRadius = 8,

        # ShadowDepth
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=8)]
        [int]$ShadowDepth = 3,

        # BlurRadius
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=9)]
        [int]$BlurRadius = 20,

        # WindowHost
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=10)]
        [object]$WindowHost,

        # Timeout in seconds,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=11)]
        [int]$Timeout,

        # Code for Window Loaded event,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=12)]
        [scriptblock]$OnLoaded,

        # Code for Window Closed event,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=13)]
        [scriptblock]$OnClosed

    )

    # Dynamically Populated parameters
    DynamicParam {
        
        # Add assemblies for use in PS Console 
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing, PresentationCore
        
        # ContentBackground
        $ContentBackground = 'ContentBackground'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.Brushes] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.ContentBackground = "White"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ContentBackground, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ContentBackground, $RuntimeParameter)
        

        # FontFamily
        $FontFamily = 'FontFamily'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)  
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.FontFamily]::Families.Name | Select -Skip 1 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($FontFamily, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($FontFamily, $RuntimeParameter)
        $PSBoundParameters.FontFamily = "Segoe UI"

        # TitleFontWeight
        $TitleFontWeight = 'TitleFontWeight'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Windows.FontWeights] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.TitleFontWeight = "Normal"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($TitleFontWeight, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($TitleFontWeight, $RuntimeParameter)

        # ContentFontWeight
        $ContentFontWeight = 'ContentFontWeight'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Windows.FontWeights] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.ContentFontWeight = "Normal"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ContentFontWeight, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ContentFontWeight, $RuntimeParameter)
        

        # ContentTextForeground
        $ContentTextForeground = 'ContentTextForeground'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.Brushes] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.ContentTextForeground = "Black"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ContentTextForeground, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ContentTextForeground, $RuntimeParameter)

        # TitleTextForeground
        $TitleTextForeground = 'TitleTextForeground'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.Brushes] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.TitleTextForeground = "Black"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($TitleTextForeground, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($TitleTextForeground, $RuntimeParameter)

        # BorderBrush
        $BorderBrush = 'BorderBrush'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.Brushes] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.BorderBrush = "Black"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($BorderBrush, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($BorderBrush, $RuntimeParameter)


        # TitleBackground
        $TitleBackground = 'TitleBackground'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.Brushes] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.TitleBackground = "White"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($TitleBackground, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($TitleBackground, $RuntimeParameter)

        # ButtonTextForeground
        $ButtonTextForeground = 'ButtonTextForeground'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.Brushes] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.ButtonTextForeground = "Black"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ButtonTextForeground, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ButtonTextForeground, $RuntimeParameter)

        # Sound
        $Sound = 'Sound'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        #$ParameterAttribute.Position = 14
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = (Get-ChildItem "$env:SystemDrive\Windows\Media" -Filter Windows* | Select -ExpandProperty Name).Replace('.wav','')
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($Sound, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($Sound, $RuntimeParameter)

        return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
    }

    Begin {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
    }
    
    Process {

# Define the XAML markup
[XML]$Xaml = @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="Window" Title="" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" Opacity="1">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border>
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border x:Name="MainBorder" Margin="10" CornerRadius="$CornerRadius" BorderThickness="$BorderThickness" BorderBrush="$($PSBoundParameters.BorderBrush)" Padding="0" >
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect x:Name="DSE" Color="Black" Direction="270" BlurRadius="$BlurRadius" ShadowDepth="$ShadowDepth" Opacity="0.6" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <Border.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DSE" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth" From="0" To="$ShadowDepth" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DSE" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BlurRadius" From="0" To="$BlurRadius" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Border.Triggers>
        <Grid >
            <Border Name="Mask" CornerRadius="$CornerRadius" Background="$($PSBoundParameters.ContentBackground)" />
            <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="$($PSBoundParameters.ContentBackground)">
                <Grid.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}"/>
                </Grid.OpacityMask>
                <StackPanel Name="StackPanel" >                   
                    <TextBox Name="TitleBar" IsReadOnly="True" IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="$Title" Padding="10" FontFamily="$($PSBoundParameters.FontFamily)" FontSize="$TitleFontSize" Foreground="$($PSBoundParameters.TitleTextForeground)" FontWeight="$($PSBoundParameters.TitleFontWeight)" Background="$($PSBoundParameters.TitleBackground)" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0"/>
                    <DockPanel Name="ContentHost" Margin="0,10,0,10"  >
                    </DockPanel>
                    <DockPanel Name="ButtonHost" LastChildFill="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                    </DockPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
"@

[XML]$ButtonXaml = @"
<Button xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="Auto" Height="30" FontFamily="Segui" FontSize="16" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10" Padding="20,0,20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Cursor="Hand"/>
"@

[XML]$ButtonTextXaml = @"
<TextBlock xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" FontFamily="$($PSBoundParameters.FontFamily)" FontSize="16" Background="Transparent" Foreground="$($PSBoundParameters.ButtonTextForeground)" Padding="20,5,20,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
"@

[XML]$ContentTextXaml = @"
<TextBlock xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Text="$Content" Foreground="$($PSBoundParameters.ContentTextForeground)" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="$($PSBoundParameters.FontFamily)" FontSize="$ContentFontSize" FontWeight="$($PSBoundParameters.ContentFontWeight)" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto" MaxWidth="500" MinWidth="50" Padding="10"/>
"@

    # Load the window from XAML
    $Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $xaml))

    # Custom function to add a button
    Function Add-Button {
        Param($Content)
        $Button = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $ButtonXaml))
        $ButtonText = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $ButtonTextXaml))
        $ButtonText.Text = "$Content"
        $Button.Content = $ButtonText
        $Button.Add_MouseEnter({
            $This.Content.FontSize = "17"
        })
        $Button.Add_MouseLeave({
            $This.Content.FontSize = "16"
        })
        $Button.Add_Click({
            New-Variable -Name WPFMessageBoxOutput -Value $($This.Content.Text) -Option ReadOnly -Scope Script -Force
            $Window.Close()
        })
        $Window.FindName('ButtonHost').AddChild($Button)
    }

    # Add buttons
    If ($ButtonType -eq "OK")
    {
        Add-Button -Content "OK"
    }

    If ($ButtonType -eq "OK-Cancel")
    {
        Add-Button -Content "OK"
        Add-Button -Content "Cancel"
    }

    If ($ButtonType -eq "Abort-Retry-Ignore")
    {
        Add-Button -Content "Abort"
        Add-Button -Content "Retry"
        Add-Button -Content "Ignore"
    }

    If ($ButtonType -eq "Yes-No-Cancel")
    {
        Add-Button -Content "Yes"
        Add-Button -Content "No"
        Add-Button -Content "Cancel"
    }

    If ($ButtonType -eq "Yes-No")
    {
        Add-Button -Content "Yes"
        Add-Button -Content "No"
    }

    If ($ButtonType -eq "Retry-Cancel")
    {
        Add-Button -Content "Retry"
        Add-Button -Content "Cancel"
    }

    If ($ButtonType -eq "Cancel-TryAgain-Continue")
    {
        Add-Button -Content "Cancel"
        Add-Button -Content "TryAgain"
        Add-Button -Content "Continue"
    }

    If ($ButtonType -eq "None" -and $CustomButtons)
    {
        Foreach ($CustomButton in $CustomButtons)
        {
            Add-Button -Content "$CustomButton"
        }
    }

    # Remove the title bar if no title is provided
    If ($Title -eq "")
    {
        $TitleBar = $Window.FindName('TitleBar')
        $Window.FindName('StackPanel').Children.Remove($TitleBar)
    }

    # Add the Content
    If ($Content -is [String])
    {
        # Replace double quotes with single to avoid quote issues in strings
        If ($Content -match '"')
        {
            $Content = $Content.Replace('"',"'")
        }
        
        # Use a text box for a string value...
        $ContentTextBox = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $ContentTextXaml))
        $Window.FindName('ContentHost').AddChild($ContentTextBox)
    }
    Else
    {
        # ...or add a WPF element as a child
        Try
        {
            $Window.FindName('ContentHost').AddChild($Content) 
        }
        Catch
        {
            $_
        }        
    }

    # Enable window to move when dragged
    $Window.FindName('Grid').Add_MouseLeftButtonDown({
        $Window.DragMove()
    })

    # Activate the window on loading
    If ($OnLoaded)
    {
        $Window.Add_Loaded({
            $This.Activate()
            Invoke-Command $OnLoaded
        })
    }
    Else
    {
        $Window.Add_Loaded({
            $This.Activate()
        })
    }
    

    # Stop the dispatcher timer if exists
    If ($OnClosed)
    {
        $Window.Add_Closed({
            If ($DispatcherTimer)
            {
                $DispatcherTimer.Stop()
            }
            Invoke-Command $OnClosed
        })
    }
    Else
    {
        $Window.Add_Closed({
            If ($DispatcherTimer)
            {
                $DispatcherTimer.Stop()
            }
        })
    }
    

    # If a window host is provided assign it as the owner
    If ($WindowHost)
    {
        $Window.Owner = $WindowHost
        $Window.WindowStartupLocation = "CenterOwner"
    }

    # If a timeout value is provided, use a dispatcher timer to close the window when timeout is reached
    If ($Timeout)
    {
        $Stopwatch = New-object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
        $TimerCode = {
            If ($Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -ge $Timeout)
            {
                $Stopwatch.Stop()
                $Window.Close()
            }
        }
        $DispatcherTimer = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
        $DispatcherTimer.Interval = [TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(1)
        $DispatcherTimer.Add_Tick($TimerCode)
        $Stopwatch.Start()
        $DispatcherTimer.Start()
    }

    # Play a sound
    If ($($PSBoundParameters.Sound))
    {
        $SoundFile = "$env:SystemDrive\Windows\Media\$($PSBoundParameters.Sound).wav"
        $SoundPlayer = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer -ArgumentList $SoundFile
        $SoundPlayer.Add_LoadCompleted({
            $This.Play()
            $This.Dispose()
        })
        $SoundPlayer.LoadAsync()
    }

    # Display the window
    $null = $window.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync{$window.ShowDialog()}.Wait()

    }
}

$Params = @{
    Content = "The file 'Important Document.docx' could not be deleted."
    Title = "File Deletion Error"
    TitleBackground = "LightGray"
    TitleFontSize = 28
    TitleFontWeight = "Bold"
    TitleTextForeground = "Red"
    ContentFontSize = 18
    ContentFontWeight = "Medium"
}
 
 $Content = "ذكرت تقارير صحفية لوكالة الأنباء رويترز نقلا عن ثلاثة مسؤولين إن وزراة التجارة الأمريكية تعتزم إصدار أمر اليوم الجمعة بمنع الأشخاص داخل الولايات المتحدة من تنزيل تطبيق وي تشات WeChat وتطبيق تيك توك TikTok ابتداء من يوم الأحد المقبل 20 سبتمبر.

وأضاف المسؤولون لوكالة رويترز أن الحظر المفروض على تطبيق تيك توك قد يتم إلغاؤه من قبل الرئيس الأمريكي، دونالد ترامب قبل أن يدخل القرار حيز التنفيذ يوم الأحد المقبل. يأتي هذا في الوقت الذي تسعى فيه شركة بايت دانس ByteDance، الشركة الأم لتطبيق تيك توك، للتوصل إلى اتفاق بشأن عملياتها داخل الولايات المتحدة.

وتجدر الإشارة إلى أن هذا الحظر جاء استجابة لأوامر تنفيذية أصدرها الرئيس الأمريكي دونالد ترامب في 6 أغسطس الماضي، أعطت وزارة التجارة 45 يوما لتحديد المعاملات التي يجب حظرها من التطبيقات التي اعتبرها تشكل تهديدا للأمن القومي، وبذلك يصبح الموعد النهائي يوم الأحد المقبل.

وكان مسؤولون في وزارة التجارة الأمريكية قد صرحوا بأنهم يتخذون إجراءات غير عادية بسبب المخاطر التي تشكلها تلك التطبيقات من خلال جمع بيانات المستخدمين، بينما نفت الشركة الصينية استخدام أي من التطبيقات في عمليات التجسس.
investing
"
 
$Params = @{
    Content = $Content
    Title = "MISSION:POSSIBLE"
    TitleFontSize = 30
    TitleTextForeground = 'Red'
    TitleFontWeight = 'Bold'
    TitleBackground = 'Silver'
    FontFamily = 'Lucida Console'
    ButtonType = 'None'
    Timeout = 30
}
 
New-WPFMessageBox @Params
```

---

***EDIT :*** Or you can download the function from the internet into `New-MsgBox.ps1` and inculde it with your main script like this example :

---

```
$MyUrlFile = "https://pastebin.com/raw/cVsJ5x2Y"
$OutPutFile = "$env:TEMP\New-MsgBox.ps1"
Invoke-WebRequest $MyUrlFile -Outfile $OutPutFile
.$OutPutFile # The dot operator is used for script include.

$Content = "ذكرت تقارير صحفية لوكالة الأنباء رويترز نقلا عن ثلاثة مسؤولين إن وزراة التجارة الأمريكية تعتزم إصدار أمر اليوم الجمعة بمنع الأشخاص داخل الولايات المتحدة من تنزيل تطبيق وي تشات WeChat وتطبيق تيك توك TikTok ابتداء من يوم الأحد المقبل 20 سبتمبر.

وأضاف المسؤولون لوكالة رويترز أن الحظر المفروض على تطبيق تيك توك قد يتم إلغاؤه من قبل الرئيس الأمريكي، دونالد ترامب قبل أن يدخل القرار حيز التنفيذ يوم الأحد المقبل. يأتي هذا في الوقت الذي تسعى فيه شركة بايت دانس ByteDance، الشركة الأم لتطبيق تيك توك، للتوصل إلى اتفاق بشأن عملياتها داخل الولايات المتحدة.

وتجدر الإشارة إلى أن هذا الحظر جاء استجابة لأوامر تنفيذية أصدرها الرئيس الأمريكي دونالد ترامب في 6 أغسطس الماضي، أعطت وزارة التجارة 45 يوما لتحديد المعاملات التي يجب حظرها من التطبيقات التي اعتبرها تشكل تهديدا للأمن القومي، وبذلك يصبح الموعد النهائي يوم الأحد المقبل.

وكان مسؤولون في وزارة التجارة الأمريكية قد صرحوا بأنهم يتخذون إجراءات غير عادية بسبب المخاطر التي تشكلها تلك التطبيقات من خلال جمع بيانات المستخدمين، بينما نفت الشركة الصينية استخدام أي من التطبيقات في عمليات التجسس.
investing
"
 
$Params = @{
    Content = $Content
    Title = "MISSION:POSSIBLE"
    TitleFontSize = 30
    TitleTextForeground = 'Red'
    TitleFontWeight = 'Bold'
    TitleBackground = 'Silver'
    FontFamily = 'Lucida Console'
    ButtonType = 'None'
    Timeout = 30
}
 
New-WPFMessageBox @Params
```

Comment: thanks but that not what I need. what you give me is what I already done... it only show the text but it not align right-to-left  and I can't use new line the txt is not readable .... what I really need is to use it Align right-to-left and also need real new line

Comment: In this case edit your question and add what did you tried as code untl now !

Comment: what I did is exactly as you did...it works for me...but as I said I want the script to support Align right-to-left and I want to know how I can make new line...

Comment: any help please